# Is it safe to publicly share Minidump files?

Tags: windows, windows-8, security, minidumps

Is it safe to publicly share `Minidump` files which are created after windows crash for like diagnosing let's say posting there links here at SO so other users can have a look and diagnose the issue??

**Does those files contain information such as username, password, ip etc. that can compromise the security of one?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sharing a Minidump is fine, because it only contains limited data:

> A small memory dump records the smallest set of useful information
>   that may help identify why your computer stopped unexpectedly. This
>   option requires a paging file of at least 2 MB on the boot volume and
>   specifies that Windows 2000 and later create a new file every time
>   your computer stops unexpectedly. A history of these files is stored
>   in a folder.
>
> **This dump file type includes the following information:**
>
> - The Stop message and its parameters and other data
> - A list of loaded drivers
> - The processor context (PRCB) for the processor that stopped
> - The process information and kernel context (EPROCESS) for the process that stopped
> - The process information and kernel context (ETHREAD) for the thread that stopped
> - The Kernel-mode call stack for the thread that stopped
>
> This kind of dump file can be useful when space is limited. However,
>   because of the limited information included, errors that were not
>   directly caused by the thread that was running at the time of the
>   problem may not be discovered by an analysis of this file.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649